# Is there an upper limit to the number of characters in a question

Tags: discussion

As a programmer, I would like to know if there is an upper limit imposed on the string length of a question/answer. And if not, how does Stackoverflow achieve unlimited string length in a database.

Comment: The other question doesn't answer your second question, so, here it is: `nvarchar(max)`